# cursor color for webkit autofilled input

Tags: html, css, autocomplete, webkit, autofill

How to force cursor for autofilled input to be the same color as for ordinary input?

In webkit autofilled input is forced to have yellow background and we use box-shadow to overlay that. But cursor reflects to background color and becomes dark relatively to browser's mechanism.

How to force it not to change it's color?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement. I used `caret-color` to apply the color to the blinking cursor. I tested it in Chrome, Edge, and Firefox, `caret-color` is [supported by major browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=caret-color) so it should work on other browsers like Safari as well.

Here is the codepen,

https://codepen.io/soyaddy/pen/XWqZVEZ